# Adding up lots of floating point numbers

Tags: floating-point

I am studying numerical analysis and I don't understand this: when adding lots of floating point numbers, the best way is to add up numbers from lowest to highest. Why is this more precise than adding up numbers from higher to lower?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why adding from biggest to smallest floating-point numbers is less accurate than adding from smallest to biggest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124692/why-adding-from-biggest-to-smallest-floating-point-numbers-is-less-accurate-than)

Answer (score 1):

Say that you are using a decimal floating-point system with 3 digits of precision. If you add the **positive** numbers 3+3+4+40+70+300+800+1000 in this order, you get the partial sums:

`6
10
50
120
420
1220
2220`

The final result is the exact sum: there was never any approximation at any step.

If you add them the other way round, you get the partial sums:

`1800
2100
2170
2210
2210
2210
2210`

Floating-point means that there is more precision around 0. In general, the goal is to make each partial sum's result be as close to zero as possible, so that each partial sum is as accurate as possible. When summing numbers of the same sign, this means adding the smaller numbers first.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a small number and a big number you may loose a lot of precision. As a simple example try adding up 10 million 1's and 20000000, using (32 bit) floats. If you add up all the ones first (getting 10 million) and then add the 20 million, you get the right answer, 30 milion. But if you start with the 20 million and add 10 million ones you end up with 20 million. This is because, in 32 bit floating point, 20 million + 1 is 20 million.